# where is the mistake with addclass?

Tags: jquery, html

i need to add class to div .panel-default but somewhere is wrong. And how to write code shortest

there is my code:

```
$('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass("style1");
  if ($(this).not(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass("style1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group type-group">
      <input type="radio" id="wallet-payment" name="payment-type" value="1">
      <label for="wallet-payment">Add Money to Wallet</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

```
$('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').toggleClass("style1", this.checked);
});
```

The problem is with the use of [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not)(it is a filter method which is used to remove the elements matching the passed argument from the calling set), which will return a jQuery object which is always truthy so irrespective of the checked state of the checkbox the `removeClass` will get executed.

Since you have radio buttons you might have to remove the class from previously selected item, so you could try

```js
$('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').click(function() {
  $('.panel-default.style1').has('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').removeClass('style1');
  $(this).closest('.panel-default').toggleClass("style1", this.checked);
});
```

```css
.style1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group type-group">
      <input type="radio" id="wallet-payment" name="payment-type" value="1" />
      <label for="wallet-payment">Add Money to Wallet</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group type-group">
      <input type="radio" id="something-else" name="payment-type" value="2" />
      <label for="something-else">Something else</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it work. you write variable var $panel where you using this?

Comment: @HaroldasKerušauskas not required

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `if-else` statement as shown below :-

```
$('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass("style1");
  else
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass("style1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your removeClass code is not getting called.

You need to use checkbox instead of radio button as you need to check/uncheck the value.also You should simply use else condition instead of second if loop:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="payment-type"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass("style1");
  else
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass("style1");
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Simple and sweet...

```
$('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').toggleClass("style1", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your latest edits you can try this one:

```js
$('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').change(function() {
  $('.style1').removeClass('style1');
  $(this).closest('.panel-default').toggleClass("style1", this.checked);
});
```

```css
.style1{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 payment-type1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group type-group">
        <input type="radio" id="wallet-payment" name="payment-type" value="1">
        <label for="wallet-payment">Add Money to Wallet</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 payment-type2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group type-group">
        <input type="radio" id="auto-payment" name="payment-type" value="2">
        <label for="auto-payment">Auto payment</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok but if i have two radio button how to removeclass then i clicked another button?

```js
$('input:radio[name="payment-type"]').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.panel-default').toggleClass("style1", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 payment-type1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group type-group">
        <input type="radio" id="wallet-payment" name="payment-type" value="1">
        <label for="wallet-payment">Add Money to Wallet</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 payment-type2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group type-group">
        <input type="radio" id="auto-payment" name="payment-type" value="2">
        <label for="auto-payment">Auto payment</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't post question in the answer's area, instead just edit your question with labeling like **edit-1**.